# How to return char 2D array double pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, c-strings, function-declaration

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

char *swap_elements(char **arr, int i)
{
    char temp[5];
    *temp = *arr;
    *arr = *(arr+i);
    *(arr+i) = *temp;
    return arr;
}

void main()
{
    char arr[][MAX_LEN]={"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"};
    int i, j;
    printf("Enter the index with which you want to swap: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    arr = swap_elements(arr, i);
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        printf("%s", *(arr+i));
}
```

This is the code that I have written for swapping the first element with the user-entered index element. But it's showing an error as below

[image: error]

Comment: You can not use a `char **` to refer to an actual two-dimensional array such as `char arr[][MAX_LEN]`.  A `char **` does not refer to a two-dimensional array, no matter what you've been told.  See [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for a good description of the difference.

Comment: You have more errors not less important  before the shown one.

Comment: Mayuresh Kulkarni, better to post errors as text rather than as a picture someplace else.

Comment: You need an array of pointers, not an array of arrays, to do what that function appears to be trying to to do. Even if you changed that, the return type and statement in `swap_elements` make no sense. Clearly `arr` in that function is `char**`. The function claims a return type of `char *`, so why would `return arr;` match that? ans: it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In this function call

```
arr = swap_elements(arr, i);
```

the array designator `arr` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element that has the type `char ( * )[MAX_LEN]`.

Also arrays do not have the assignment operator. So this statement

```
arr = swap_elements(arr, i);
```

is incorrect.

You need to declare the function like

```
void swap_elements( char ( *arr )[MAX_LEN], int i);
```

Within the function you are trying to assign a pointer to the object of the type `char`

```
char temp[5];
*temp = *arr;
```

that does not make a sense.

Instead you need to copy strings stored in character arrays.

The function can be defined the following way

```
#include <string.h>

void swap_elements( char ( *arr )[MAX_LEN], int i)
{
    char temp[MAX_LEN];

    strcpy( temp, *arr );
    strcpy( *arr, *( arr + i );
    strcpy( *( array + i ), temp );
}
```

Another approach is to declare an array of pointers instead of the multi-dimensional array.

For example

```
char * arr[] = {"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"};
```

In this case the function will look like

```
void swap_elements( char **arr, int i)
{
    char *temp;

    temp = *arr;
    *arr = *( arr + i );
    *( array + i ) = temp;
}
```

Pay attention to that you need to check within the function that the passed index is not greater than the array size. Otherwise the function is unsafe. So you need to add one more parameter to the function that will specify the number of elements in the passed array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to actually achieve what you are trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

void swap_elements(char* arr, int i)
{
    char temp[MAX_LEN];
    strncpy(temp, arr, MAX_LEN);
    strncpy(arr, arr+i*MAX_LEN, MAX_LEN);
    strncpy(arr+i*MAX_LEN, temp, MAX_LEN);
}

void main()
{
    char arr[][MAX_LEN]={"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"};
    int swapTarget;
    printf("Enter the index with which you want to swap: ");
    scanf("%d", &swapTarget);
    swap_elements(arr, swapTarget);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%s", arr[i]);
}
```

To understand why I did it like this first you need to understand how multidimensional arrays are stored in C.

When you for example have this array:

```
int arr2d[5][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10}}
```

It will be stored like this:

```
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
```

And when you try to access the 2nd array 2nd element element with `arr2d[1][1]` C basically converts it to: `*(arr2d + 1*2 + 1)`. 2 here representing the size of one of the subarrays(in your case `MAX_LEN`).

So when I write `arr+i*MAX_LEN` it is the same as writing `arr[i]` but you have to do it manually.

Also you can't move strings around like this `*arr = *(arr+i)`. This would only  move the i-th character of arr into the place of the first character of arr.

Which is why you have to use either `strcpy` or `strncpy`. The difference being that with `strncpy` you define the length of the string to be moved while with `strcpy` it copies until it gets to a null-byte.